# Javascript/jQuery - how do I get a parent element from within multiple iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm working within a setup that I have no control over:

Parent->Iframe->Iframe->My document

How do I access an element that is on the parent from within my document?

These are all on the same domain, so no cross-domain issues. I can do this with either straight up JS or jQuery.

I've been searching around, but haven't found any examples of someone trying to access an element on the top from the bottom through multiple iframes!

The solution, in case anyone else comes across this:

```
var p = $("#Viewport",window.top.document); 
alert(p.attr('name'));
```

Comment: How would you access an element contained in a parent if there were only one iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `window.top`, like:

```
console.log(top.document.getElementById('someInputId').value);
```

Notice that `window` in implicit, so you can leave it off. Of course, you will have to change `'someInputId'` to an input id on your top page to see if this works. Use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value` if you are testing against an Element that is not an input.

Comment: Error: top.getElementById is not a function.

Comment: I left out the `document` property of the `top` window. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be able to access this via window.parent, as thus:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('target-element');
```

Comment: I'm getting a null error. Sample code:

Viewport in parent:
`<meta id="Viewport" name="viewport">`

In my iframe
`var p = window.parent.document.getElementById('Viewport');`
`alert(p.getAttribute("name"));`